# rake task has to run a controller method every 2 minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, whenever

The rake task has to run a method (index) in downloads_controller every 2 minutes. so i installed [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem. and in "config/schedule.rb" file i added.

```
every 2.minutes do
 rake "*****"                 
end
```

I don't know how to give my action(app/controller/downloads_controller.rb->index)directory after rake.is there anything has to modify in other files? anyone please help me.

updated code

```
every 1.minutes do
  rake "Download.index"
end
```

and moved index method to Download model. 
and how to check whether rake task working or not?

Comment: Why you want to run controller action from rake?
Ideally that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Better you can move your business logic to `Model` and you can call your `Model method` in `rake`

Comment: my actual task is i have to download a file from a paticular url for every some x minutes.so i written the logic in index method which is in download_controller.

Comment: Ok. How you are getting that url in `Controller`?
I guess you can used same url in `Model` and used Model method in rake.

Comment: ya..i moved the method into Download model and changed the code to             
 " runner 'Download.index' "      but still not working...thanks for reply

Comment: @vjnan369........try my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now its working for me....

i moved method implementation to "downloader.rake" file which added at lib/tasks.
the code in downloader.rake is

```
namespace :downloader do
desc "download a file"
task:downloading => :environment do
Rails.logger.info("message from task")
.......method implementation........
end
end
```

i scheduled the above implementation in "schedule.rb" in config file

```
every 2.minutes do
rake "downloader:downloading"
end
```

here "downloader" is the name of the rake file and "downloading" is the task name

Answer (score 2):

Ok. How are you getting that url in `Controller`?
I guess you can use the same url in the `Model` and use the Model method in the rake.

Comment: i moved index method to model and i changed to "rake 'Download.index' " but to no avail.  @Sourabh

Comment: What is inside "index" action?

Comment: You can check your log to ensure that your background job working. http://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log